# Simple retrier of async function

Tags: javascript, async-await

I wrote a simple function for retrying the passed function in case it throws.
I did it for my app that needs to call an external API through the network, which may spuriously fail.

```
export async function retry(fn, retries, delayMs, onFailedAttempt = null) {
    let lastError = null;

    for (let attempt = 0; attempt <= retries; attempt++) {
        if (attempt > 0) {
            await delay(delayMs);
        }

        try {
            const res = await fn();
            return res;
        } catch (error) {
            if (onFailedAttempt) {
                onFailedAttempt(error, attempt, retries, delayMs);
            }

            if (window.verbose) {
                console.debug(`Trial ${attempt + 1}/${retries} failed. Retrying in ${delayMs}ms...`);
            }

            lastError = error;
        }
    }

    throw lastError;
}
```

This seems to work, do you folks think I have overlooked any corner case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code looks good and will work well. I have made some minor improvements to improve readability and reduce redundancy.

```
export async function retry(fn, retries, delayMs, onFailedAttempt) {
  let attempt = 0;

  while (true) {
    try {
      return await fn();
    } catch (error) {
      if (onFailedAttempt) {
        onFailedAttempt(error, attempt, retries, delayMs);
      }

      if (window.verbose) {
        console.debug(`Trial ${attempt + 1}/${retries} failed. Retrying in ${delayMs}ms...`);
      }

      if (attempt++ < retries) {
        await delay(delayMs);
      } else {
        throw error;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Improvements:

1. `onFailedAttempt = null` in the function signature is redundant. If `onFailedAttempt` is not passed as an argument, its value will be `undefined`. Which will work equally well in your case when checking its value.
2. Moving `await delay(delayMS)` in catch block to keep related code together. As we only delay when an error occurs and if this was not the last attempt.
3. `const res = await fn()`, `res` is not needed here. You can simply do `return await fn()`.
4. We could use the `do...while` here, but we'll have to check the `attempt < retries` condition two times in that situation. By using `while (true)`, we only have to check it once.
5. We can also remove the `lastError` variable. If we get an error and this was the last attempt, we simply `throw error`.

Comment: Thank you for the review! As a solo developer it is really helpful to be able to have other dev looking at my code :) I like how to put the delay in the catch block. On the other hand, I still find the for loop more readable than a do while, but that's subjective :)

Comment: @LouisCoulet I have updated the code to make it even better. Yes, you are right, you can use a `for`, `while`, or a `do...while` loop here. It's all subjective. Even from a performance perspective, it doesn't matter much. However, If there is less code, there will be less issues.

Comment: +1, but still think while(true) makes the code harder to read, now I have to read the count to know how this gets out.

Comment: Thank you, I find this version even more readable! Though the main point is correctness and robustness against corner cases, the loop syntax is secondary (to me at least)

Answer (score 0):

Loved your little function and decided to give a shot at changing it. Whether you like it more or less is for you to decide, but I will try to outline principles and goals which I tried to achieve with my modification and would be happy to hear any feedback, suggestions and even criticisms are all very welcome.

So let's start with the function straight away:

```
export async function retry({ 
            taskFn, retries = 3 , delay = 1000, onFailedAttempt = null, logDebug = null }) {

    let attempt = 0;
    let allErrors = [];
    logDebug  = logDebug || _logDebug;

    do{
      attempt++;
      try{
        await runDelay({ skipDelay: attempt === 1});
        return await taskFn();
      }
      catch(err){
        allErrors.push(err);
        logFailure(err);
        notifyFailure(err);
      }
    } while( shouldWeContinueRetrying() );

    throw createFinalError({
      message: `Operation failed after ${retries} retries. ` + 
               `Last error message: ${allErrors[allErrors.length-1].message}`,
      code: `RTRY_FAIL`,
      allErrors, 
    })

    // -------------------------------------
    // ---------- UTILS / VERBS ------------
    // -------------------------------------
    function notifyFailure(err){
      if ( onFailedAttempt ){
        onFailedAttempt(err, attempt, retries);
      }
    }

    function logFailure(err){
      logDebug(`Trial ${attempt}/${retries} failed with reason: ${err.message}`);
    }

    async function runDelay({ skipDelay }){
      if ( skipDelay ) return;
      if ( !delay ) return;
      
      const millis = 'function' === typeof delay ? delay(attempt, retries) : delay;
      logDebug(`Retrying in ${millis}ms...`);
      await bluebird.delay(millis);
    }

    function shouldWeContinueRetrying(){
      return attempt < retries;
    }

    function createFinalError({ message, code, allErrors}){
      const error = new Error(message);
      error.code = code;
      error.allErrors = allErrors;
      return error;
    }

    function _logDebug(msg){
      if ('undefined' == typeof window) return;
      if (!window.verbose ) return;
      console.debug(msg);
    }

  }
```

So let's start with the main loop:

- in previous variants of code there was this nesting (`if`s mostly) due to which my eye had difficulty grasping what is the core logic of the main loop
- here I attempt to show that main loop is trivially simple `runDelay() and calling taskFn()`
- looking at catch clause: my intention was to show that there are just 3 conceptual operations involved in catching  error: saving all errors, logging, notifying. 3 simple trivial steps.
- you can also notice that I am saving all of the errors. In previous code only lastError was saved, but actually it almost doesn't cost us anything to save all errors instead of last one (eg. for troubleshooting; I admit it is not a very important change, but it was easy and makes me happy)
- I introduced logFailure() because conceptually it fits perfectly with how mind is thinking about this step: failure will be logged there. The 'How' aka 'implementation' is not important. It could be console, it could be winston or ignore
- when I typed `logFailure(err)` it came out almost naturally to type below `notifyFailure(err)` also because those two steps align perfectly with how mind conceptualizes what actually should happen there. (And same here: how exactly notification happens, via direct function call or EventEmitter instance doesn't matter; what matters is the conceptual step of {notifying about failure}).
- I suspect that readers may not like the `while( shouldWeContinueRetrying() )`  when it could be simply replaced by `while( attempt < retries )` ! In this case I fully admit that abstracting here was an overkill. I also admit that it is part of my "personal coding style" to create small "conceptual functions" (which internally refer to as 'verbs') and then compose code out of them.  So let me know what you think here and whether it was confusing or if you think it's an overkill.
- Whether you liked my approach or think it looks ugly, my intention was to make main loop as compact and succinct as possible.  And in my intention to make main loop logic straightforward: I even used the `skipDelay` trick to avoid using `if`.
  So instead of `if ( attempt !== 1 ) await runDelay()` I used:
  `await runDelay({ skipDelay: attempt === 1})`. With actual if hidden within `runDelay`. I admit that this is part of "my personal coding style" and would welcome any thoughts and feedbacks. If it is something you use and if you see ways to improve that.

```
        let attempt = 0;
    let allErrors = [];

    do{
      attempt++;
      try{
        await runDelay({ skipDelay: attempt === 1});
        return await taskFn();
      }
      catch(err){
        allErrors.push(err);
        logFailure(err);
        notifyFailure(err);
      }
    } while( shouldWeContinueRetrying() );
```

---

Function main logic finishes with throwing an error:

```
// .... omitted .... 
} while( shouldWeContinueRetrying() );

    throw createFinalError({
      message: `Operation failed after ${retries} retries. ` + 
               `Last error message: ${allErrors[allErrors.length-1].message}`,
      code: `RTRY_FAIL`,
      allErrors, 
    })
```

After the main loop I wanted to have one visually apparent "return value" (which in our case is an error thrown), exactly like in Louis Coulet's original code.  Whilst `throw lastError` is perfect, but as I decided to store {all errors}, I had problem of concisely assembling this custom error object.

As I wanted code to fit well into StackExchange answer (and fit into single file) I didn't want to declare my own custom error in separate file. If opted for custom Error class I could throw with succinct `throw new FailedAllRetriesError(`Operationfailed`, 'RTRY_FAIL`, allErrors)`. So the second best thing was just to throw using 'factory function'.

I am neither happy nor unhappy with this error throwing. The main point here was to clearly show "return value" (error thrown) upon exit of the function.

Before I jump into actual **verbs,** let me quickly clear air around 2 boring utility functions:

```
        // simply factory function which is meant to make 
    // call to createFinalError() more concise
    function createFinalError({ message, code, allErrors}){
      const error = new Error(message);
      error.code = code;
      error.allErrors = allErrors;
      return error;
    }

    // This is encapsulation of 'logging a message',
    // as you can see from the first lines of the function 
    //
    // export async function retry({  ...... , logDebug = null }) {
    // logDebug  = logDebug || _logDebug;
    // 
    // Caller can pass alternative to logDebug() implementation
    // and hence customize logging logic
    function _logDebug(msg){
      if ('undefined' == typeof window) return;
      if (!window.verbose ) return;
      console.debug(msg);
    }
```

#### **The Verbs**

Now the most interesting part.

There are 4 what I refer to as 'verb functions'. They are named after 'conceptual steps' which our little algorithm is comprised of.

Note that:

- notifyFailure - has same functionality as OP
- logFailure - I think I found bug and fixed it
- runDelay - I added new functinality: `delay` parameter passed to `retry()` can now be a function returning delay period in milliseconds.

```
// This is 'verb' for {notifying about failure}
// All it does is simply dispatches onXX hook function passed
// as function option, but nothing prohibits is from dispatching 
// it via EventEmtiter or other mechanism in the future. 
function notifyFailure(err){
  if ( onFailedAttempt ){
    onFailedAttempt(err, attempt, retries);
  }
}

// This is simplest 'verb' it simply logs failure 
// (by delegating to whatever logging mechanism is wired to logDebug()

// However note:that I have _removed_ logging of the delay! 
// Check out original line:
//
// console.debug(
//    `Trial ${attempt + 1}/${retries} failed. Retrying in ${delayMs}ms...`
// );
//
// It turns out that logging delay and logging error are two separate tasks
// and unless my mind plays tricks on me, I spotted bug in 
// both Lous and sg7610 variations where 
// '... Retrying in ${delayMs}ms...' would be logged 
// even after last attempt failed when there will be no actual retry or waiting.
function logFailure(err){
  logDebug(`Trial ${attempt}/${retries} failed with reason: ${err.message}`);
}

async function runDelay({ skipDelay }){
  // This is the trick I used to pull 'if' from the caller to inside of 'runDelay()`
  // I created this `runDelay`verb in order 
  // so that I can locally make it 'smarter' 
  
  if ( skipDelay ) return;

  // This is another attempt to clear call site. Instead of guarding
  // against delay at callsite, it is guarded here. 
  if ( !delay ) return;

  // Below I added NEW FUNCTIONALITY
  // Now `delay` parameter can be a function. Which will be called
  // to get next value of the delay period in milliseconds. 

  // This can be used to create eg. 'Exponential backoff' during retries.
  const millis = 'function' === typeof delay ? delay(attempt, retries) : delay;
  // Also notice that {delay logging} is now inside actual runDelay()
  logDebug(`Retrying in ${millis}ms...`);
  await bluebird.delay(millis);
}

// I already mentioned that you may probably see shouldWeContinueRetrying() 
// as an overkill, but in my mind it is still such a clearly defined 
// conceptual step that it deserves being manifested as function in the code;
// I  doesn't feel too guilty about this one :)
function shouldWeContinueRetrying(){
  return attempt < retries;
}
```

So this is my take on the original function implementation. Let me know which parts you would change, which you think were helpful to you and which were controversial. I do recognize that at of of 'local functions' is part of my personal coding style, and very curious to see what you would make out of it.

I have made [replit.com](http://replit.com) nodeJS package for it. You can run it by running `npm start` from the "Shell" tab on the right. (Just pressing 'Run' button didn't work for me).  See the link to replit below:

https://replit.com/join/qneqgpuu-dimitrykireyenk

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview! Whenever you post an alternative solution please try to share with us what sort of benefits does it have over the OP's solution.

Comment: @PeterCsala thank you! I will update the post to include benefits!